# How to round an average to 2 decimal places in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am using PostgreSQL via the Ruby gem 'sequel'.

I'm trying to round to two decimal places.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(some_column),2)    
FROM table
```

I get the following error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does 
not exist (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

I get no error when I run the following code:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(some_column))
FROM table
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code in your question.

Comment: The syntax error aside, this [closely related question on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21036/3684) sheds some light on rounding double precision numbers in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @muistooshort, Thanks for pointing that out. It should say 'round' where it says 'avg'. Edited.

Comment: for searching results sake, I also get this hint as output from the prompt: `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 438, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not define `round(double precision, integer)`. For reasons *@Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'* explains in the comments, the version of round that takes a precision is only available for `numeric`.

```
regress=> SELECT round( float8 '3.1415927', 2 );
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

regress=> \df *round*
                           List of functions
   Schema   |  Name  | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+--------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | dround | double precision | double precision    | normal
 pg_catalog | round  | double precision | double precision    | normal
 pg_catalog | round  | numeric          | numeric             | normal
 pg_catalog | round  | numeric          | numeric, integer    | normal
(4 rows)

regress=> SELECT round( CAST(float8 '3.1415927' as numeric), 2);
 round 
-------
  3.14
(1 row)
```

(In the above, note that `float8` is just a shorthand alias for `double precision`. You can see that PostgreSQL is expanding it in the output).

You must cast the value to be rounded to `numeric` to use the two-argument form of `round`. Just append `::numeric` for the shorthand cast, like `round(val::numeric,2)`.

---

If you're formatting for display to the user, don't use `round`. Use `to_char` (see: [data type formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) in the manual), which lets you specify a format and gives you a `text` result that isn't affected by whatever weirdness your client language might do with `numeric` values. For example:

```
regress=> SELECT to_char(float8 '3.1415927', 'FM999999999.00');
    to_char    
---------------
 3.14
(1 row)
```

`to_char` will round numbers for you as part of formatting. The `FM` prefix tells `to_char` that you don't want any padding with leading spaces.

Comment: Hmm. When I try out `ROUND(CAST(FLOAT8 '3.1415927' AS NUMERIC),2);`, I get '0.314E1'. And I have my code written as `ROUND(AVG(val),2)` yet still get the error I described in my question.

Comment: I just ran `ROUND(CAST(FLOAT8 '3.1415927' AS NUMERIC),2);` on PgAdmin and Ruby. With PgAdmin, I get 3.14, but with Ruby (using he Sequel gem) I get '0.314E1'. I wonder why this is...

Comment: *"For some odd reason the version of round that takes a precision is only available for numeric."* Floating-point numbers are "useful approximations". If you ask code to round a floating-point number to two decimal places, returning *another* floating-point number, there's no guarantee that the closest approximation to the "right" answer will have only two digits to the right of the decimal. Numerics are effectively scaled integers; they don't have that problem.

Comment: @Catcall Good point - a `double` version of `round` would need to return `numeric` or (ugh) `text`, so it might as well take a `numeric` argument.

Comment: @user1626730 Ruby, or Ruby's `pg` gem, must do weird things with `numeric` values. Are you formatting it for display to the user? If so, see updated answer.

Comment: @user1626730 If you're still seeing an error after casting to numeric, please show your real code.

Comment: @CraigRinger It does seem that the gem does weird things. However, your TO_CHAR code worked. The result has blank spaces at the beginning of it, but I can strip those off with Ruby.

Comment: @user1626730 As per the documentation, if you don't want the padding for the sign use the `FM` version, eg `SELECT to_char(float8 '3.1415927', 'FM999999999.00')`. Answer amended.

Comment: For those trying to find the comment by @Catcall : now it is _Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'_

Comment: ROUND(value::numeric,2) -- when value is float8

Comment: When I use `round((price / (weight / 1000)::numeric), 2) as price_per_kg`, I get this weird "scientific notation" output like 0.8e-1 instead of 0.08. How can I fix it?

Comment: @JoreJoh use the `format` function or other number-to-text formatting functions to display it in your preferred form

Answer (score 168):

((this is a Wiki!  please edit to enhance!))

Try also the old syntax for casting,

```
SELECT ROUND( AVG(some_column)::numeric, 2 ) FROM table;
```

works with any version of PostgreSQL.
 ...But, as definitive solution, you can [overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) the ROUND function.

### Overloading as casting strategy

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ROUND(float,int) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $f$
  SELECT ROUND( CAST($1 AS numeric), $2 )
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Now your instruction will works fine, try this complete comparison:

```sql
SELECT trunc(n,3), round(n,3) n_round, round(f,3) f_round,
       pg_typeof(n) n_type, pg_typeof(f) f_type, pg_typeof(round(f,3)) f_round_type
FROM (SELECT 2.0/3.0, 2/3::float) t(n,f);
```

| trunc | n_round | f_round | n_type | f_type | f_round_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.666 | 0.667 | 0.667 | numeric | double precision | numeric |

The *ROUND(float,int)* function is `f_round`, it returns a (decimal) NUMERIC datatype, that is fine for some applications: problem solved!

In another applications we need a float also as result.  An alternative is to use `round(f,3)::float`  or to create a `round_tofloat()` function.
Other alternative, overloading `ROUND` function again,  and using all range of [**accuracy-precision**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) of a floating point number, is to return a float when the accuracy is defined (see [IanKenney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16246957/287948)),

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ROUND(
  input float,     -- the input number
  accuracy float   -- accuracy, the "counting unit"
) RETURNS float AS $f$
   SELECT ROUND($1/accuracy)*accuracy
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Try

```sql
  SELECT round(21.04, 0.05);     -- 21.05 float!
  SELECT round(21.04, 5::float); -- 20
  SELECT round(1/3., 0.0001);    -- 0.3333
  SELECT round(2.8+1/3., 0.5);   -- 3.15
  SELECT round(pi(), 0.0001);    -- 3.1416
```

PS: the command `\df round`, on `psql`  after overloadings, will show something like this table

```
 Schema     |  Name | Result  | Argument  
------------+-------+---------+------------------
 myschema   | round | numeric | float, int
 myschema   | round | float   | float, float
 pg_catalog | round | float   | float            
 pg_catalog | round | numeric | numeric   
 pg_catalog | round | numeric | numeric, int
```

where *float* is synonymous of `double precision` and *myschema* is `public` when you not use a schema.  The `pg_catalog` functions are the default ones, see at Guide the [build-in math functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html).

### Rounding and formating

The `to_char` function apply internally the *round* procedure, so, when your aim is only to show a final result in the terminal, you can use the [`FM` modifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE) as a prefix to a numeric format pattern:

```sql
SELECT round(x::numeric,2), trunc(x::numeric,2), to_char(x, 'FM99.99')
FROM (SELECT 2.0/3) t(x);
```

| round | trunc | to_char |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.67 | 0.66 | .67 |

---

### NOTES

#### Cause of the problem

**There are a lack of overloads** in some PostgreSQL functions, why (???):  I think "it is a lack" (!), but @CraigRinger, @Catcall and the PostgreSQL team agree about *"pg's historic rationale"*.

#### Note about performance and reuse

The build-in functions, such as ROUND of the pg_catalog, can be overloaded with no performance loss, when compared to direct cast encoding. Two precautions must be taken when implementing user-defined **cast functions for high performance**:

- The `IMMUTABLE` clause is very important for code snippets like this, because, as said in the Guide: *"allows the optimizer to pre-evaluate the function when a query calls it with constant arguments"*
- PLpgSQL is the preferred language, except for "pure SQL". For [JIT optimizations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit-reason.html) (and sometimes for parallelism) `language SQL` can obtain  better optimizations. Is something like copy/paste small piece of code instead of use a function call.

Conclusion: the above `ROUND(float,int)` function, after optimizations, **is so fast than** @CraigRinger's answer; it will compile to (exactly) the **same internal representation**. So, although it is not standard for PostgreSQL, it can be standard for your projects, by a centralized and reusable "library of snippets", like  [pg_pubLib](https://github.com/AddressForAll/pg_pubLib-v1).

---

#### Round to the nth bit or other numeric representation

Some people argue that it doesn't make sense for PostgreSQL to round  a number of float datatype, because **float is a binary representation**, it requires rounding the number of bits or its hexadecimal representation.

Well, let's solve the problem, adding an exotic suggestion... The aim here is to  return a *float* type in another overloaded function,
   `ROUND(float, text, int) RETURNS float` 
The `text` is to offer a choice between

- `'dec'` for "decimal representation",
- `'bin'` for "binary" representation and
- `'hex'` for hexadecimal representation.

So, in different representations we have a **different interpretation about the number of digits** to be rounded. Rounding a number *x* with an approximate shorter value, with less "fractionary digits" (tham its original *d* digits), will be  shorter when *d* is couting  binary digits instead decimal or hexadecimal.

It is not easy without C++, using "pure SQL", but this code snippets will illustrate and can be used as workaround:

```sql
-- Looking for a round_bin() function! this is only a workaround:
CREATE FUNCTION trunc_bin(x bigint, t int) RETURNS bigint AS $f$
    SELECT ((x::bit(64) >> t) << t)::bigint;
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
 
CREATE FUNCTION ROUND(
   x float, 
   xtype text,  -- 'bin', 'dec' or 'hex'
   xdigits int DEFAULT 0
) 
RETURNS FLOAT AS $f$
    SELECT CASE
       WHEN xtype NOT IN ('dec','bin','hex') THEN 'NaN'::float
       WHEN xdigits=0 THEN ROUND(x)
       WHEN xtype='dec' THEN ROUND(x::numeric,xdigits)
       ELSE (s1 ||'.'|| s2)::float
      END
    FROM (
      SELECT s1,
             lpad( 
               trunc_bin( s2::bigint, CASE WHEN xd<bin_bits THEN bin_bits - xd ELSE 0 END )::text,
               l2,
               '0'
             ) AS s2
      FROM (
        SELECT *, 
             (floor( log(2,s2::numeric) ) +1)::int AS bin_bits, -- most significant bit position
             CASE WHEN xtype='hex' THEN xdigits*4 ELSE xdigits END AS xd
        FROM (
          SELECT s[1] AS s1, s[2] AS s2, length(s[2]) AS l2
          FROM (SELECT regexp_split_to_array(x::text,'\.')) t1a(s)
        ) t1b
      ) t1c
    ) t2
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Try

```sql
 SELECT round(1/3.,'dec',4);     -- 0.3333 float!
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'dec',1); -- 3.1 float!
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'dec');   -- ERROR, need to cast string 
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'dec'::text); -- 3 float
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'dec',0); -- 3 float

 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'hex',0); -- 3 float (no change)
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'hex',1); -- 3.1266
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'hex',3); -- 3.13331578486784

 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'bin',1);  -- 3.1125899906842625
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'bin',6);  -- 3.1301821767286784
 SELECT round(2.8+1/3.,'bin',12); -- 3.13331578486784
```

And `\df round` have also:

```
 Schema     |  Name | Result  | Argument  
------------+-------+---------+---------------
 myschema   | round | float   | x float, xtype text, xdigits int DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: See also the new duplicated [*"Is there a function to round a floating point number directly?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20933882/287948)

Answer (score 49):

Try with this:

```
SELECT to_char (2/3::float, 'FM999999990.00');
-- RESULT: 0.67
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT round (2/3::DECIMAL, 2)::TEXT
-- RESULT: 0.67
```

Comment: I find this to be the much more concise and strait forward move on with my day answer to this question. :bow:

Comment: Same here! Very short and useful solution.

Comment: This is not an algebric solution, it is valid only for print report.

Answer (score 22):

you can use the function below

```
 SELECT TRUNC(14.568,2);
```

the result will show :

```
14.56
```

you can also cast your variable to the desire type :

```
 SELECT TRUNC(YOUR_VAR::numeric,2)
```

Comment: Same problem,  need cast to numeric and returns numeric

Comment: this isn't rounding, to be exact. the output for your suggestion is 14.56, whereas if you round that number, it would be 14.57

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(amount)::numeric, 2) AS total_amount
FROM transactions
```

Gives: 200234.08

Answer (score 10):

Try casting your column to a numeric like:

```
SELECT ROUND(cast(some_column as numeric),2) FROM table
```

Comment: working in pg10 without casting with numeric values.

Comment: @SergioBelevskij `ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist`, the cast as numeric is needed.

Comment: Try to cast value into numeric: `round (cast(doublecolumn as numeric),2)` if your pg version under 10.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Bryan's](http://postgresql.nabble.com/float-to-numeric-7-3-td5552098.html) response you can do this to limit decimals in a query. I convert from km/h to m/s and display it in dygraphs but when I did it in dygraphs it looked weird. Looks fine when doing the calculation in the query instead. This is on postgresql 9.5.1.

```
select date,(wind_speed/3.6)::numeric(7,1) from readings;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Error:function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

**Solution**: You need to addtype cast then it will work

Ex:  `round(extract(second from job_end_time_t)::integer,0)`