# PostgreSQL - rounding floating point numbers

Tags: postgresql

I have a newbie question about floating point numbers in PostgreSQL 9.2.

Is there a function to round a floating point number directly, i.e. without having to convert the number to a numeric type first?

Also, I would like to know whether there is a function to round by an arbitrary unit of measure, such as to nearest 0.05?

When casting the number into a decimal form first, the following query works perfectly:

```
SELECT round(1/3.::numeric,4);

 round  
--------
 0.3333
(1 row)
Time: 0.917 ms
```

However, what really I'd like to achieve is something like the following:

```
SELECT round(1/3.::float,4);
```

which currently gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist at character 8
Time: 0.949 ms
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can accomplish this by doing something along the lines of

```
select round( (21.04 /0.05 ),0)*0.05
```

where `21.04` is the number to round and `0.05` is the accuracy.

Answer (score 17):

Your workaround solution works with any version of PostgreSQL,

```sql
SELECT round(1/3.::numeric,4);
```

But the answer for *"Is there a function to round a floating point number directly?"*, is **no**.

### The cast problem

You are reporting a well-known "bug", **there is a lack of overloads** in some PostgreSQL functions... Why (???):  I think "it is a lack" (!), but @CraigRinger, @Catcall (see  [comments at Craig's anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113623/287948)) and the PostgreSQL team agree about *"PostgreSQL's historic rationale"*.

The solution is to develop a centralized and reusable "library of snippets", like  [pg_pubLib](https://github.com/AddressForAll/pg_pubLib-v1). It implements the strategy described below.

### Overloading as casting strategy

You can [overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) the build-in ROUND function with,

```sql
 CREATE FUNCTION ROUND(float,int) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $f$
    SELECT ROUND($1::numeric,$2);
 $f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Now your dream will be reality, try

```sql
  SELECT round(1/3.,4); -- 0.3333 numeric
```

It returns a (decimal) NUMERIC datatype, that is fine for some applications... An alternative is to use `round(1/3.,4)::float`  or to create a `round_tofloat()` function.

Other alternative, to preserve input datatype and use all range of [accuracy-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) of a floating point number (see [IanKenney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16246957/287948)), is to return a float when the accuracy is defined,

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION ROUND(
  input    float,    -- the input number
  accuracy float     -- accuracy
) RETURNS float AS $f$
   SELECT ROUND($1/accuracy)*accuracy
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION ROUND(float,float) IS 'ROUND by accuracy.';
```

Try

```sql
 SELECT round(21.04, 0.05);     -- 21.05 
 SELECT round(21.04, 5::float); -- 20 
 SELECT round(pi(), 0.0001);    -- 3.1416
 SELECT round(1/3., 0.0001);    -- 0.33330000000000004 (ops!)
```

To avoid floating-pont truncation (internal information loss), you can "clean" the result, for example truncating  on 9 digits:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION ROUND9(
  input    float,    -- the input number
  accuracy float     -- accuracy
) RETURNS float AS $f$
   SELECT (ROUND($1/accuracy)*accuracy)::numeric(99,9)::float
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Try

```sql
  SELECT round9(1/3., 0.00001);  -- 0.33333 float, solved!
  SELECT round9(1/3., 0.005);    -- 0.335 float, ok!
```

PS: the command `\df round`, on `psql`  after overloadings, will show something like this table

```
 Schema     |  Name | Result  | Argument  
------------+-------+---------+------------------
 myschema   | round | numeric | float, int
 myschema   | round | float   | float, float
 pg_catalog | round | float   | float            
 pg_catalog | round | numeric | numeric   
 pg_catalog | round | numeric | numeric, int
```

where *float* is synonymous of `double precision` and *myschema* is `public` when you not use a schema.  The `pg_catalog` functions are the default ones, see at Guide the [build-in math functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html).

---

### More details

See a complete [Wiki answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934099/287948).