# Rounding SUM (Float ) to one Decimal in PostGreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding

I want to round off the sum to one decimal i'm trying this below

```
round(sum(cast(expend as float)/1000),1) AS "ROUNDING TO ONE DECI"
```

It says as `function round(double precision, integer) does not exist`

Please can anyone say about this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113623/5110151

Comment: Datatype should be `numeric` in PostgreSQL

Comment: or this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: I don't know who closed this.. this question is not answered anywhere in the above link. The question is to round a return value from sum() function. You can;t apply above solutions, it gives nested function call not allowed error.