# Postgres Division decimals

Tags: postgresql

I have an Insert in a table (ex. field a1) which is a calculated value in a SELECT field01Value/1000000 .

How can I format the field to display 20 or more decimals after the operation.
I tried CAST(field01Value as double precision)/1000000 but the value is displayed as 2E-5.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a cast to [`numeric(precision, scale)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) instead. Scale would be 20 in your case, and precision the maximum number of digits you would allow.

```
select field01Value/1000000::numeric(30,20)
from mytable
```

Demo here : https://dbfiddle.uk/DLfdUN_Y

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you may use the `ROUND()` function and the `::numeric` cast to show the calculated result with a given number of decimal places without using scientific notation. Here's an illustration:

```
SELECT (field01Value::numeric / 1000000)::numeric(30, 20) AS calculated_value
FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried ROUND function ?

```
SELECT ROUND(field01Value::numeric / 1000000, 20) AS calculated_value
FROM table;
```

Seems duplicate :- [How to round an average to 2 decimal places in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113096/how-to-round-an-average-to-2-decimal-places-in-postgresql)