# Calculating percentage in a table is giving correct and wrong answers with the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-15

I have a table with year, area codes and each area code has 5 categories of age groups with people count as below.

| year | areacode | agegroup | persons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | code 1 | 20-29 | 5 |
| 2021 | code 2 | 30-39 | 11 |
| 2022 | code 1 | 20-29 | 7 |
| 2022 | code 2 | 30-39 | 5 |
| 2020 | code 1 | 20-29 | 0 |
| 2020 | code 2 | 30-39 | 6 |
| 2019 | code 1 | 20-29 | 0 |
| 2019 | code 2 | 30-39 | 0 |

I need to calculate percentage of persons for each group out of total persons per areacode, the result I need is:

| fid | year | areacode | agegroup | persons | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | code 1 | 20-29 | 5 | 31.3% |
| 2 | 2021 | code 2 | 30-39 | 11 | 68.8% |
| 3 | 2022 | code 1 | 20-29 | 7 | 58.3% |
| 4 | 2022 | code 2 | 30-39 | 5 | 41.7% |
| 5 | 2020 | code 1 | 20-29 | 0 | 0.0% |
| 6 | 2020 | code 2 | 30-39 | 6 | 100.0% |
| 7 | 2019 | code 1 | 20-29 | 0 | 0.0% |
| 8 | 2019 | code 2 | 30-39 | 0 | 0.0% |

But the result I'm getting is bizarre, it is partially giving correct answers and also wrong answers. See below result.

| fid | year | areacode | agegroup | persons | total_sum | test | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | code 1 | 20-29 | 5 | 16 | 1 | 0.0% |
| 2 | 2021 | code 2 | 30-39 | 11 | 16 | 1 | 0.0% |
| 3 | 2022 | code 1 | 20-29 | 7 | 12 | 1 | 0.0% |
| 4 | 2022 | code 2 | 30-39 | 5 | 12 | 1 | 0.0% |
| 5 | 2020 | code 1 | 20-29 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 0.0% |
| 6 | 2020 | code 2 | 30-39 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 100.0% |
| 7 | 2019 | code 1 | 20-29 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.0% |
| 8 | 2019 | code 2 | 30-39 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.0% |

Any percentage that is other than 0 or 100, is resulting in 0%
To test the total_sum column, I added the test column where the total is 0 give 0, else 1. And that works perfectly fine.

I'm using the following code:

```
select 
    table.fid, 
    table.year, 
    table.areacode,
    table.agegroup,
    table.persons,
    totals.total_sum,
    case
        when totals.total_sum = 0 then 0
        else 1
    end as test,
    case
        when totals.total_sum = 0 then 0
        else ((table.persons)/totals.total_sum)*100.0
    end as percent
from abc.table
join (
    select
        table.year,
        table.areacode,
        sum(table.persons) as total_sum
    from abc.table
    group by table.areacode, table.year) as totals
on table.areacode = totals.areacode and table.year=totals.year
group by table.areacode, table.fid, table.year, table.agegroup, totals.total_sum
order by totals.total_sum
```

I tried finding anything related to this kind of error, but unfortunately, I didn't find anything (Maybe, I'm using the wrong keywords).

Does anyone know why is this happening? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The percent column is being calculated as an integer, most likely because of `when totals.total_sum = 0 then 0`. Try changing that block to `when totals.total_sum = 0 then 0.0  else (table.persons/totals.total_sum)*100.0`. Does that change things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer division discards remainders. You need to change one integer into a float before the division is done. Just move the constant upfront and inside the parentheses

```
(100.0*table.persons/totals.total_sum)
```

Comment: Thanks @jjanes yours is the only solution that worked. It's just that now all the answers are given in numeric with 17 decimals, I'll figure out how to restrict to 2 decimals. Thanks again for this solution with explanation, it makes sense.

Comment: found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113096/how-to-round-an-average-to-2-decimal-places-in-postgresql#:~:text=You%20must%20cast%20the%20value,val%3A%3Anumeric%2C2)%20.&text=to_char%20will%20round%20numbers%20for,any%20padding%20with%20leading%20spaces. round((100.0*table.persons/totals.total_sum),2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.year, 
       t.areacode, 
       t.agegroup, 
       COALESCE(t.persons, 0) AS persons, -- Replace null with 0
       total_by_year.total_persons,
       (COALESCE(t.persons, 0) / total_by_year.total_persons) * 100 AS percentage -- Replace null with 0
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT year, SUM(COALESCE(persons, 0)) AS total_persons -- Replace null with 0
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY year
) AS total_by_year ON t.year = total_by_year.year  
ORDER BY t.year DESC
```

You can try with this query. It will be good if you add the primary key so that will be helpful for the sorting.

[image]